# PHP - Regular expressions to match a string like this : 2012/018843/06?

Tags: php, regex

I do not know very much about regular expressions but would like to create a regex to validate a string like this: `2012/018843/06.

If it may help someone in the future, I would like to say that would be for a South African Company Registration Number.

If anyone would be kind enough to post a regex that can be processed via PHP and does match this, that would be great. If not, any links to "the basics" of creating regular expressions in this manner would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

EDIT:

I have tried this:

`[0-9/]{14}`

But it does not match the length exactly.

Comment: are the numerics fixed in length? then try `#\d{4}/\d{6}/\d{2}#`

Comment: "4 digits slash six digits slash 2 digits" ? seems pretty easy. a) what have you tried? b) is the expression more complex that I've stated?

Comment: http://ch.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php to learn the expressions. Especially the meta-characters are very important. Those include for example .+*? and different brackets.

Comment: @John3136 I have edited my post to provide an example of what i did try, and it is not more complex. That is the exact string, always (the numbers will differ of course)

Comment: @Slomo Thank you for the link, I will read through it!

Comment: If your data is so regular, don't use regular expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are the numerics fixed in length? then try

```
preg_match('#^\d{4}/\d{6}/\d{2}$#', $string)
```

syntax:

- `\d` is an escape sequence which represents any decimal digit (0-9), this could also be represented by `[0-9]`
- `{4}` defines, that the last expression (in this case: a decimal
  digit) has to occur 4 times, using this expression avoids repeating the previous expression many times, so `\d{4}` means `\d\d\d\d`
- `^` represents the beginning of the
  string and `$` the end of the string, so this ensures, that there are
  no other chars in this string, so a string like `abc2012/018843/06def` would not match

Comment: that looks about perfect, could you please explain it a little bit? Thanks!

Comment: BTW: if the length vary, then you can define i.e. `{4,8}` instead of `{6}` which means, that there could be 4-8 decimal digits.

Answer (score 3):

In it's simplest form:

```
preg_match("|^\d{4}/\d{6}/\d{2}$|", $input);
```

The `\d` token matches any integer 0 - 9, the integer inside `{}` indicates how many repetition are allowed from the previous tokens, the `/` matches literal `/` since I'm using `|` as the regex delimiter.

The `^` token is to match from the beginning of the string, and `$` to match the end of string, this way, things like `aa2012/124521/11bb` won't match (it would match otherwise if you take out the `^$`)

Comment: could you please see the other answer and give an explanation as to why you have chosen this?